# Passing reference/static data through a viewmodel to a view in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a class to hold some static data:

```
static public class ReferenceData
    {
        [DisplayName("Status")]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusType
        {
            get
            {
                return new[]
                    {
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Release" },
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Beta" },
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Alpha" },
                    };
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to use that class data to populate a drop down list in a view. I have the following view model:

```
public class adminViewModel
{
    public HouseData   HouseData { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public ReferenceData ReferenceData { get; } // <<<<<< My problem here
}


@Html.DropDownListFor(
  x => x.Status,
  new SelectList(Model.ReferenceData.StatusType, "Value", "Text"),
  new { style = "display: inline;" }
)
```

The problem for me is that I am not sure if this is a valid way to do it because I am using a static class and when I have the get; there inside of the {} it complains during compile with an error message saying:

```
static types cannot be used as return types
```

Do I really need to make it a non-static and instantiate the class before I can use it in the viewmodel even though the data is always static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not valid C#. You could use a static method instead:

```
public static class ReferenceData
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStatusType()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Release" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Beta" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Alpha" },
        };
    }
}
```

and then :

```
public class AdminViewModel
{
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Statuses
    {
        get
        {
            return ReferenceData.GetStatusType();
        }
    }
}
```

finally in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Status,
    new SelectList(Model.Statuses, "Value", "Text"),
    new { style = "display: inline;" }
)
```

Comment: except that kind of data should be in the viewbag, or viewdata, or tempdata. anywhere but the viewmodel.  that data has nothing to do with the model.

Comment: @nathan gonzalez, ViewBag and ViewData being the most evil things in ASP.NET MVC for me this kind of data should definitely not be there. TempData, I don't know => there are some rare cases where this might be useful. I think you mean that this data could be hardcoded in a repository method that the controller action queries in order to populate the model. Then I would agree with you.

Comment: hardcode in a repository?  i don't think i would ever do that.  why would you hate viewbag and viewdata.  this type of data is what they are designed for. the viewmodel is for the views model, which this data clearly is not a part of.

Comment: @nathan gonzalez, yes I would have an implementation of my repository interface that I would for example call `AdminOptionsMemory` because for example I don't have database and I don't want to store those values in files, I just want them in memory. As far as ViewBag/ViewData are concerned those introduce weak typing into the views, if you use them it means that you don't use strongly typed views and view models, if you use them you don't get Intellisense, if you use them you need to perform casts in your views in order to invoke the proper overload of the method, ... and I can go on with this

Comment: i'm not saying you should not use a strongly typed view, i'm all for using the viewmodel for model related view data.  and i get the weakly typed issue, but for data that is not present in the views model, viewdata is the place to put it.  i suppose agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want your class to be static and not the property? If you have a static property, you don't have to create an instance in order to access a property. More info: [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx):

Comment: I wanted to make the class static so I would not have to instantiate it. Is that a correct statement? I removed static from the class and added static to status type. Then in the view model I get a different message: .....ReferenceData.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors.

Comment: make the property static instead of class

Comment: @DavidH if you want ReferenceData to be a read-only automatically implemented property, then you should write public ReferenceData ReferenceData { get; private set; }

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this:

```
    public class ReferenceData
    {
        private static readonly SelectListItem[] Items = new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Release" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Beta" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Alpha" },
                };

        [DisplayName("Status")]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusType
        {
            get { return Items; }
        }
    }
```

(make the items static while using an class instance).

You can also use a singleton:

```
    public class ReferenceData
    {
        private static readonly ReferenceData _instance = new ReferenceData();

        private ReferenceData()
        {

        }

        public ReferenceData Instance { get { return _instance; } }

        [DisplayName("Status")]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusType
        {
            get
            {
                return new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Release" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Beta" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Alpha" },
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

And to use it in your model:

```
public class adminViewModel
{
    public HouseData   HouseData { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public ReferenceData ReferenceData { get {return ReferenceData.Instance; } }
}
```

Comment: Your answer works very good. Just one question. How can I access the StatusType in a C# program. I tried to do var data1 = new ReferenceData(); but it comes up with an error message Reference data is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: `var data = ReferenceData.Instance.StatusType`

Answer (score 0):

First Of all Create your Model like this..

```
public class ReferenceData
{
    public string SelectRuleId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusType
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Release" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Beta" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Alpha" },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Then Create new action in any controller like this..

```
   public ActionResult About()
    {
        var model = new ReferenceData();

        ViewBag.Message = "DropDown Selected For ";

        return View(model);
    }
```

Then Use this Html in your action view...

```
@model MVCDropDownList.Models.AnswersViewModel

 @using (Html.BeginForm())  
    {  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectRuleId , new SelectList(Model.StatusType, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "DId" })  
    }
```